# java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 members with a @ValueRangeProvider annotation must not have the same id (timeslotRangeLS)

Tags: python, optapy

Trying to generate school timetable with lab hours.
Kindly help me to solve this error! Thanks in advance.

Here is my code!

```
@planning_solution
class TimeTable:
    timeslot_list: list[Timeslot]
    timeslot_list1: list[Timeslot]
    room_list: list[Room]
    lesson_list: list[Lesson]
    lab_list: list[Lab]
    score: HardSoftScore

    def __init__(self, timeslot_list, timeslot_list1, room_list, lesson_list,lab_list, 
score=None):
        self.timeslot_list = timeslot_list
        self.timeslot_list1 = timeslot_list1
        self.room_list = room_list
        self.lesson_list = lesson_list
        self.lab_list = lab_list
        self.score = score

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Timeslot)
    @value_range_provider("timeslotRangeLS")
    def get_timeslot_list(self):
        return self.timeslot_list

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Timeslot)
    @value_range_provider("timeslotRangeLB")
    def get_timeslot_list1(self):
        return self.timeslot_list1

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Room)
    @value_range_provider("roomRange")
    def get_room_list(self):
        return self.room_list

    @planning_entity_collection_property(Lesson)
    def get_lesson_list(self):
        return self.lesson_list

    @planning_entity_collection_property(Lab)
    def get_lab_list(self):
        return self.Lab_list

    @planning_score(HardSoftScore)
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"TimeTable("
            f"timeslot_list={format_list(self.timeslot_list)},\n"
            f"timeslot_list1={format_list(self.timeslot_list1)},\n"
            f"room_list={format_list(self.room_list)},\n"
            f"lesson_list={format_list(self.lesson_list)},\n"
            f"lab_list={format_list(self.lab_list)},\n"
            f"score={str(self.score.toString()) if self.score is not None else 'None'}"
            f")"
        )
```

Trying to get the 2 timeslots one for lesson(1 hour) and one for lab(2 hour).Here is my @planning_solution.

I defined 2 @planning_entity for both lab & lesson with @value_range_provider.

```
@planning_entity
class Lab(Base):
    id: int
    subject: str
    teacher: str
    student_group: str
    timeslot1: Timeslot
    room: Room

    def __init__(self, id, subject, teacher, student_group, timeslot1 = None, room=None):
        self.id = id
        self.subject = subject
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.student_group = student_group
        self.timeslot1 = timeslot1
        self.room = room
    @planning_variable(Base, value_range_provider_refs=['roomRange', 'timeslotRangeLB'],
                            graph_type=PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    
    
    @planning_variable(Timeslot, ["timeslotRangeLB"])
    def get_timeslot1(self):
        return self.timeslot1

    @value_range_provider(range_id = "timeslotRangeLB", value_range_type = Timeslot)
    def get_possible_timeslot_list1(self):
        return self.subject.teacher.student_group.room_list
    
    
    def set_timeslot1(self, new_timeslot):
        self.timeslot1 = new_timeslot
    @planning_variable(Room, ["roomRange"])
    def get_room(self):
        return self.room

    def set_room(self, new_room):
        self.room = new_room

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"Lab("
            f"id={self.id}, "
            f"timeslot1={self.timeslot1}, "
            f"room={self.room}, "
            f"teacher={self.teacher}, "
            f"subject={self.subject}, "
            f"student_group={self.student_group}"
            f")"
        )
@planning_entity
class Lesson(Base):
    id: int
    subject: str
    teacher: str
    student_group: str
    timeslot: Timeslot
    room: Room

    def __init__(self, id, subject, teacher, student_group, timeslot=None, room=None):
        self.id = id
        self.subject = subject
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.student_group = student_group
        self.timeslot = timeslot
        self.room = room
    @planning_variable(Base, value_range_provider_refs=['timeslotRangeLS', 'roomRange'],
                            graph_type=PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED)
    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    @planning_variable(Timeslot, ["timeslotRangeLS"])
    def get_timeslot(self):
        return self.timeslot

    @value_range_provider(range_id = "timeslotRangeLS", value_range_type = Timeslot)
    def get_possible_timeslot_list(self):
        return self.subject.teacher.student_group.room_list
        # return self.course.teacher.department.room_list
    
    def set_timeslot(self, new_timeslot):
        self.timeslot = new_timeslot
    
    @planning_variable(Room, ["roomRange"])
    def get_room(self):
        return self.room

    def set_room(self, new_room):
        self.room = new_room

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"Lesson("
            f"id={self.id}, "
            f"timeslot={self.timeslot}, "
            f"room={self.room}, "
            f"teacher={self.teacher}, "
            f"subject={self.subject}, "
            f"student_group={self.student_group}"
            f")"
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you defined `@value_range_provider(range_id = "timeslotRangeLS")` on both your `@planning_solution` and your `@planning_entity`. You can only have one; if you want the value range to apply to every entity, do it on the `@planning_solution`. If you want each planning entity to have it own value range that only applies to it, do it on the `@planning_entity`. If you want to combine a value range that contains common values for all entities, and a value range that is per entity, use a `@value_range_provider` on the `@planning_solution`, and a `@value_range_provider` on the entity, but give them different ids (ex: `@value_range_provider(range_id = "timeslotRangeLSSolution")` and `@value_range_provider(range_id = "timeslotRangeLSEntity")`, and in the `@planning_variable`, use both range ids in the list (ex: `@planning_variable(Room, ["timeslotRangeLSSolution", "timeslotRangeLSEntity"])`